# How can I translate my Android app name?

Tags: android, localization, translation

I'm making an Android app and I want to make it available in English and in Brazilian Portuguese. I know that I can translate the string and the whole app but can I translate the app name too or I must make another app?

Comment: @Rohan re edit: please don't put `arbitrary` words in `code blocks` - that isn't what code blocks `are` for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add values to every language you want support

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

For example You have to add values-prt and add strings.xml file and there add translated strings
Then in strings you have to also add name of your app

Comment: so the one in `values` takes the default name?

Comment: Yes, strings.xml in values folder are default

Answer (score 2):

No, you can have one app that supports all languages using qualifiers.

You write the app's name in the localized strings and also in the developer console. The developer console name is what it's name will be in the play store and the localized strings is what your app will be called in the launcher

Answer (score 2):

Set the name of your application in your manifest :

android:name="@string/app_name"
or 
android:label="@string/app_name"

And use [localized](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html) strings.xml files