# Android does not display translated app name

Tags: android

Mainfest:

```
<application android:name="org.qtproject.qt.android.bindings.QtApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    ...
    <activity android:name="net.mynamespace.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|mcc|mnc|density"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ...
```

`res` directory contains Russian translation:

```
values/strings.xml
values-ru/strings.xml
```

`values/strings.xml` content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">English App Name</string>
</resources>
```

`values-ru/strings.xml` content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Russian App Name</string>
</resources>
```

but devices with Russian language still display English app name.

What can be wrong?

Tried `values-b+ru` but it did not help.

If I copy `values-ru/strings.xml` to `values/strings.xml` the app name is displayed in Russian.

Did a quick Google search, but with no success:

1. [How can I translate my Android app name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658981/how-can-i-translate-my-android-app-name)
2. [Support different languages and cultures](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)
3. [Using resources for localization](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization)
4. [What is the list of supported languages/locales on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android)

Comment: doesn't the name change if you close and reopen the app ??

Comment: @DrHowdyDoo no, it does not, even if I reboot the device.

Comment: try removing the `android:configChanges`  tag from the manifest file

Comment: @DrHowdyDoo removed `android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|mcc|mnc|density"` and reinstalled the app, but it did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it helped me that I commented out this line in the `android/build.gragle` file:

```
defaultConfig {
    //resConfig "en"        //this one
    minSdkVersion = qtMinSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion = qtTargetSdkVersion
{
```

And I also created two additional folders, in addition to the already existing `android/res/values`:

- `android/res/values-en`
- `android/res/values-ru`

In each of the three folders, I put a `strings.xml` file to make it look like this:

- `android/res/values/strings.xml`
- `android/res/values-en/strings.xml`
- `android/res/values-ru/strings.xml`

Each file must contain the name of the application corresponding to the language described by two characters in the name of the folder in which it is located.